# What does it mean when someone asks "what's on the register?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I was joking around with a friend saying I'm accepting wedding presents already despite not being prepared for marriage just yet, then she asked:

> What's on the register?

I googled it and the only thing that came up is "on the register", based on the definitions I think it means like what's on the list? But I could be wrong. So what does it really mean?

Comment: I expect she means *What "requested wedding presents" have you tentatively written into the "register" of presents **requested / already offered by another guest**?*  It's just a facetious joke, since you shouldn't be preparing your list of requested wedding presents when you haven't even set a wedding date yet! But it's a dynamically-modified "register", not *just* the "static" list of things you want (like a child's "begging letter" to Santa). Once you start to circulate it, it'll be continuously updated as future guests select / reserve the specific present *they* promise to give you.

Answer (score 2):

A *wedding registry* is a list of items that a couple would like to receive as gifts at their wedding. They usually distribute this list at about the same time as they send out wedding invitations.

In a conversation about weddings, you can just say "registry" and everyone will understand.

So your friend was asking you what items are on the list of things you want people to give you at your wedding.